# Как закрыть jFrame?

Tags: java

Привет, наверное очень глупый вопрос но сталкиваюсь с таким впервые, вот я открываю новый jFrame

```
new ViewEditImage().setVisible(true);
```

а потом хочу его закрыть.

Так:

```
new ViewEditImage().setVisible(false);
```

И так:

```
jPanel1.setVisible(false);
```

Ничего не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать самый элементарный способ закрытия - `System.exit(0)`.

Или - `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Либо если вы хотите, чтобы графический интерфейс работал так, как если бы вы нажали кнопку закрытия `X`, то вам нужно отправить событие закрытия окна в `Window`. `ExitAction` из [Закрытия Приложения](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) позволяет вам добавить эту функциональность в элемент меню или любой компонент, который легко использует `Action`.

`frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`

[Ссылка на оригинал ответа в английском варианте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)

Comment: Спасибо, но решил проблему еще проще, командой dispose()

Comment: @RickPetrev можно и так, вариантов много.